# .replace() not replacing desired string

Tags: python, regex

I am using a simple '.replace()' function on a string to replace some text with nothing as so:

```
.replace("('ws-stage-stat', ", '')
```

I have also tried using a regex to do this, like so:

```
match3a = re.sub("\(\'ws-stage-stat\', ", "", match3a)
```

This string is extracted from the source code for the following webpage at line 684:

http://www.whoscored.com/Regions/252/Tournaments/26

I have extracted and cleaned up the rest of the code into some usable data, but this one last bit won't co-operate and stubbornly refuses to be replaced. This seems like a very straight forward problem, but it just won't work for me.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: there is no need to escape `'`. Try `\('ws-stage-stat', `

Answer (score 2):

The first replacement *should* work. Make sure that you're assigning the result of the replacement somewhere, for example:

```
mystring = mystring.replace("('ws-stage-stat', ", '')
```

Comment: my full syntax is exactly as above, but it is not working still. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you aren't escaping the regex correctly.

This is code my "Patterns" app spit out:

```
re.sub("\\(\\'ws-stage-stat\\', ", "", match3a)
```

A quick test showed me that it works correctly.

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying. Why are double backslashes used in your example, rather than single? I tried adding this to my Scrapy code, but it still did not substitute the string.

Comment: For some reason I was only able to get this to work my replacing the '(', '-' and text body in separate .replace() statements. Strange...

Comment: You need the backslashes escaping the backslashes so Python assembles a correct regex in the string with only single backslashes. Using single backslashes in a string gets Python to think you want to use a general (non-regex) escape sequence like \n, \r etc.

Comment: the backslashes aren't in the string being parsed, they are escaping the "'" characters.